# Array of int - Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, c, arrays

If I make this line in C\C++:

```
int myArray[10] = { 0 }; // all elements 0
```

I will have an array of ten zeros. 
How can I make in the same mode an array in Javascript, without `for loop` and `push` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an array of **`11`** `undefined` elements
2. `join` them by using `0` as string
3. `split` the array by empty string
4. Use `map` to convert the strings to number

```js
var myArray = new Array(11).join('0').split('').map(Number);

console.log(myArray);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(myArray, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

> **Use this**

```
Array(10).fill(0);
```

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Examples